# compare content of UIButton Selected state

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am learning objective-c for iOS programming.  I am making an app that has 2 round rect buttons and a label.  I want to compare the values of the content of the buttons and output text to the label based on whether the buttons match or not.  I have not been able to figure out how to compare the content of the buttons though.  I have a model file and the view controller that I'll post below.

Thanks for any help you can provide

This is model.h file

```
//  MatchTest.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MatchTest : NSObject

-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender;
-(NSString*)doesItMatchGroup:(NSArray *)buttonGroup;

@end
```

This is model.m file

```
//  MatchTest.m
#import "MatchTest.h"

@implementation MatchTest

-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString* tempString;

    if(sender.isSelected)
    {
        tempString = @"selected";
    }
    else
    {
        tempString = @"not selected";
    }

    return tempString;
}

-(NSString*)doesItMatchGroup:(NSArray *)buttonGroup
{
    NSString* tempString = @"Buttons: Match";;

    for(int i=1;i<buttonGroup.count;i++)
    {
        if(buttonGroup[i-1] != buttonGroup[i])
        {
            tempString = @"Buttons: Do Not Match";
            NSLog(@"%@",buttonGroup[i]);
        }

    }

    return tempString;
}
@end
```

This is ViewController.h file

```
//  MatchViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MatchTest.h"
@interface MatchViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

This is ViewController.m file

```
//  MatchViewController.m
#import "MatchViewController.h"

@interface MatchViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *matchLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MatchTest *match;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonGroup;

@end

@implementation MatchViewController

-(MatchTest *)match
{
    if(!_match) _match = [[MatchTest alloc] init];
    return _match;
}

-(NSArray *)buttonGroup
{
    if(!_buttonGroup) _buttonGroup = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return _buttonGroup;
}

- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected;
    self.matchLabel.text = [self.match doesItMatchGroup:self.buttonGroup];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I figured out exactly how it needs to work @rmaddy I really appreciate your help.  your suggestions really helped me finish this!  Here is my solution:

Match.h

```
//  MatchTest.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MatchTest : NSObject
-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender;//kept for legacy purposes
-(NSString*)doButtonsMatch:(NSArray *)buttonGroup;
@end
```

Match.m

```
//  MatchTest.m
#import "MatchTest.h"

@implementation MatchTest


-(NSString*)doesItMatch:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString* tempString;

    if(sender.isSelected)
    {
        tempString = @"selected";
    }
    else
    {
        tempString = @"not selected";
    }

    return tempString;
}

-(NSString*)doButtonsMatch:(NSArray *)buttonGroup
{
    NSString *returnString;

    NSString *tempString;
    NSString *otherString;

    int count = 0;

    for (UIButton *button in buttonGroup)
    {
        if(button.isSelected)
        {
            tempString = [button titleForState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
        else {tempString = [button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];}

        for(UIButton *otherButton in buttonGroup)
        {
        count++;

        if(otherButton.isSelected)
        {
           otherString = [otherButton titleForState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
        else {otherString = [otherButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];}

        NSLog(@"%i - %@ - %@",count,tempString,otherString);

        if (![tempString isEqual:otherString])
        {
            returnString = @"Button: Unmatched";
            break;
        }
        else{returnString = @"Button: Matched";}
    }

    if (![tempString isEqual:otherString]){break;}
}

return returnString;
}
@end
```

and then the MatchViewController.m

```
//  MatchViewController.m
#import "MatchViewController.h"

@interface MatchViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *matchLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MatchTest *match;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonGroup;
@end

@implementation MatchViewController
-(MatchTest *)match
{
if(!_match) _match = [[MatchTest alloc] init];
return _match;
}

-(NSArray *)buttonGroup
{
    if(!_buttonGroup) _buttonGroup = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return _buttonGroup;
}

- (IBAction)button:(UIButton *)sender
{
    sender.selected = !sender.isSelected; //flips the button
    self.matchLabel.text = [self.match doButtonsMatch:self.buttonGroup];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `buttonGroup` array contains `UIButton` objects, then your code for `doesItMatchGroup` needs to be updated to properly compare the titles of the buttons. At least I believe that is your intended goal. You are unclear by what you mean by "compare the values of the content of the buttons".

Assuming you want to see if the button titles match then you do this:

```
- (NSString *)doesItMatchGroup:(NSArray *)buttonGroup {
    NSString* tempString = @"Buttons: Match";

    for (int i = 1; i < buttonGroup.count; i++) {
        UIButton *btn1 = buttonGroup[i - 1];
        UIButton *btn2 = buttonGroup[i];
        NSString *title1 = [btn1 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSString *title2 = [btn2 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (![title1 isEqualToString:title2]) {
            tempString = @"Buttons: Do Not Match";
            NSLog(@"%@",buttonGroup[i]);
            break; // no need to check any more buttons
        }
    }

    return tempString;
}
```

Comment: that's almost perfect.  I have the value **front** for the default state and the value **back** for the selected state. I'd like the method to compare the values and determine equality.  Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

And thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. What is it exactly that you need done differently?

Comment: title1 and title2 are always showing the default value of the button, they are never changing to the selected state

Comment: I still don't follow your exact requirements but if you need the title for the selected state then pass in `UIControlStateSelected`.

Comment: I'm building up to a matching game. I want to compare the content that appears in the _selected title_ window (under attributes of a round rect button) of one button to the content of another button